# Can the dependent samples t test be used for this problem?

Tags: volatility, statistical-significance, risk-parity

**Short story:**

I have 2 sets of data:

- Set 1: Vector with daily data of stock market returns (eg. [1%, 1.2%, -2%])
- Set 2: That vector of stock market returns, multiplied by another vector (eg. [2%, 0.6%, -1%] which equals [1% * 2, 1.2% * 0.5, -2% * 0.5])

I want to test the hypothesis that data set 1 has a mean that's equal to the mean of data set 2 *when you adjust for the variance*.

Can the dependent samples t test be used for this? If not, how can I do it?

---

---

**Long Story:**

I want to test the profitability's significance of a strategy that has a variable portfolio weight. That weight is dependent on the volatility of the past X days of data, and the adjustment is made so that the expected volatility is equal to a given target.

In the data set 1, I've got 20K+ days of data where the average daily return is ~0,**0**25% with a daily standard deviation of ~0,63%.

On data set 2, when I adjust for the standard deviation, the return is ~0,**00**24%. Intuitively, it would seem that with 20K points of data, the difference in the means would be pretty significant because the two data sets are always going to be very correlated (.8+ in this case). But the p-value is .50, random.

I would think that this t test isn't appropriate because the data set 1 has a direct influence on the results of the data set 2, in a way that doesn't happen in the other cases where this test is applied. I was thinking about making a Monte Carlo simulation where I multiply data set 1 by a vector with random numbers, where those numbers have the same statistical properties as the numbers that I used in data set 2.

Thank you.

Comment: p-values usually have worth when you reject the null hypothesis, i.e. p<0.05, but your p-value is significantly far from that so that indicates good confidence. Have you considered Welch's t-test which accounts for the different variances of two series? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test

Comment: My conundrum is that I should be rejecting the null hypothesis because of the huge discrepancy between the data sets (mean of 0.025% vs 0.0024% when I adjust for the variance with 20K+ data points), especially when I consider the fact that the two data sets are always going to be highly correlated. The Welch's t-test assumes that the samples are independent. Am I right to assume that in this problem is different from your typical dependent samples example (differences in the same patients before and after treatment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to test the hypothesis of equal *Sharpe Ratio* (or rather, the population analogue thereof). The usual test for this, with paired observations, is via the Delta method, as first described by Jobson & Korkie, and later by [Leung & Wong](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=907270), among others. In R you can perform this test via `SharpeR::sr_equality_test`. As a caution, the power of this test increases as the correlation of the assets goes to 1, as outlined in section 4.3 of the [Short Sharpe Course](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3036276); with increased statistical power comes increased statistical responsibility!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I'm a little puzzled, since if you have a set of observations, $x_t$, and you derive an estimator of the population mean: $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_t x_t$, and then you take some scalars $a_t$ conditioned on a variance then your new estimator is $\bar{x_a} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_t x_ta_t$.

You are now asking the question is $\bar{x} = \bar{x_a}$. The answer is almost surely no, it isn't. And no tests are required, its mathematically defined.

But if you treated $a_t$ as some random variable you could define some statistics.

For example suppose that $a_t$ were i.i.d from a $\mathcal{N} (1, \sigma^2)$ then the expectation of the new mean is the same: $E[\bar{x_a}|x_t] = \bar{x}$, but this depends on the expectation of $a_t$ being 1.

And it has a variance of the following:
$$Var(\bar{x_a}) = \sum_{i,j} \frac{x_i x_j}{N^2} Cov(a_i, a_j)$$

Since we said that $a_t$ was iid then $Cov(a_i,a_j)=\delta_{ij} \sigma^2$, so that the $Var(\bar{x_a}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{N^2}\sum_t x_t^2$.

So that in this case, $\bar{x_a} \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x},  \frac{\sigma^2}{N^2}\sum_t x_t^2)$.

However, this all hinged on the expectation of $a_t$ being 1, if it isn't then technically the expectation of the 'new' mean is not the same as the 'old' mean. I would suggest a statistical test that measures whether your $a_t$ (if assumed to be random variables) have a mean of 1, and for that you can use one sample students t-test (if your $a_t$ are normally distributed, which you can also test with a normality test).

Comment: Yes, $a_t$ is not a static variable, but $\bar{a_t}$ also not 1 -- it will depend on $Var(x_t)$ and the target $Var(x_a)$ that I set. I want to test the hypothesis that $E[\bar{x_a}| Var(x_t) = Var(x_a)] = \bar{x_t}$.

Comment: It won't be, guaranteed, unless $E[\bar{a_t}]=1$.